# -[WKWebView _cancelOperation:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance - When pressing "ESC" on WkWebview input

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, capacitor

Dealing with an issue where this exception:

> Exception NSException *   "-[App.MyBrandWebView _cancelOperation:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x119027400"   0x0000600000cfb9c0

Is thrown whenever the "ESC" key is typed into an input focused in a WkWebView. For context, this is a hybrid web-view based application and we are using a custom WKWebView superclass.

Initially, I assumed this issue would be trivial and could be solved by defining this `_cancelOperation` function on the `MyBrandWebView` subclass but this seems to have no effect:

```swift
class MyBrandWebView: WKWebView {

  @objc func _cancelOperation(sender: Any?) {
    
  }
  
  
  @objc func cancelOperation(sender: Any?) {
    
  }
}
```

I was looking through the inhertance chain of a `WKWebView` and I struggle to see where this `cancelOperation` is defined, or more importantly, why it's being triggered with the escape key.

Here's the relevant stack trace

```
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001804658a8 __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000018005c09c objc_exception_throw + 56
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018047a6f8 +[NSObject(NSObject) instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:] + 0
    3   UIKitCore                           0x0000000110a7b3d4 -[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 232
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001804699f8 ___forwarding___ + 1280
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018046bd1c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
    6   UIKitCore                           0x000000011084fe28 -[UIKeyboardImpl _cancelOperation:testOnly:] + 636
    7   UIKitCore                           0x00000001108512a8 -[UIKeyboardImpl handleKeyCommand:repeatOkay:options:] + 3760
    8   UIKitCore                           0x0000000110880e80 -[UIKeyboardImpl _handleKeyCommandCommon:options:] + 72
    9   UIKitCore                           0x0000000110880e28 -[UIKeyboardImpl _handleKeyCommand:] + 16
    10  UIKitCore                           0x00000001108665b4 -[UIKeyboardImpl handleKeyTextCommandForCurrentEvent] + 236
    11  WebKit                              0x0000000107d8b3bc -[WKContentView(WKInteraction) _interpretKeyEvent:isCharEvent:] + 160
    12  WebKit                              0x000000010789f8c4 _ZN6WebKit14PageClientImpl17interpretKeyEventERKNS_22NativeWebKeyboardEventEb + 48
    13  WebKit                              0x00000001078c4cb0 _ZN6WebKit12WebPageProxy17interpretKeyEventERKNS_11EditorStateEbON3WTF17CompletionHandlerIFvbEEE + 140
    14  WebKit                              0x0000000107cda790 _ZN6WebKit12WebPageProxy21didReceiveSyncMessageERN3IPC10ConnectionERNS1_7DecoderERN3WTF9UniqueRefINS1_7EncoderEEE + 3268
    15  WebKit                              0x0000000107dc260c _ZN3IPC18MessageReceiverMap19dispatchSyncMessageERNS_10ConnectionERNS_7DecoderERN3WTF9UniqueRefINS_7EncoderEEE + 276
    16  WebKit                              0x00000001079eb928 _ZN6WebKit15WebProcessProxy21didReceiveSyncMessageERN3IPC10ConnectionERNS1_7DecoderERN3WTF9UniqueRefINS1_7EncoderEEE + 40
    17  WebKit                              0x0000000107dbe6f0 _ZN3IPC10Connection15dispatchMessageENSt3__110unique_ptrINS_7DecoderENS1_14default_deleteIS3_EEEE + 728
    18  WebKit                              0x0000000107dbff58 _ZN3WTF6Detail15CallableWrapperIZN3IPC10Connection16SyncMessageState22processIncomingMessageERS3_RNSt3__110unique_ptrINS2_7DecoderENS6_14default_deleteIS8_EEEEE3$_5vJEE4callEv + 636
    19  JavaScriptCore                      0x000000010d2dc3d4 _ZN3WTF7RunLoop11performWorkEv + 176
    20  JavaScriptCore                      0x000000010d2dd0e4 _ZN3WTF7RunLoop11performWorkEPv + 32
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001803c669c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001803c65e4 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 172
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001803c5d54 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 232
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001803c043c __CFRunLoopRun + 768
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001803bfd28 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
    26  GraphicsServices                    0x000000018986ebc0 GSEventRunModal + 160
    27  UIKitCore                           0x0000000110a4ffdc -[UIApplication _run] + 868
    28  UIKitCore                           0x0000000110a53c54 UIApplicationMain + 124
    29  App                                 0x00000001001fc684 main + 64
    30  dyld                                0x00000001003d1558 start_sim + 20
    31  ???                                 0x00000001004b6058 0x0 + 4299907160
    32  ???                                 0x8343000000000000 0x0 + 9458403642408173568
)
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get this to work by defining a runtime selector on the subclass like so:

```swift
    let block: @convention(block) (AnyObject?) -> Void = { (self: AnyObject!) -> Void in }
    let imp = imp_implementationWithBlock(unsafeBitCast(block, to: AnyObject.self))
    class_addMethod(MyBrandWebView.self, NSSelectorFromString("_cancelOperation:"), imp, "i@:@")
```

Don't think this is the correct solution, but it works. So I'll share.